# How to read data via streamreader from csv file as it is.. means it should come as string

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am reading csv file via streamreader. Issue is that in csv file if if the data is like "Read" then steamreader the same data is coming as ""Read"". How to remove this extra inverted commas?

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor do you see the extra inverted commas?

Comment: Yes If I open the file in test editor there are Inverted commas on all the values which are supposed to be string.

Comment: Why not simply `str = str.Replace("""", "")`?

Comment: Does the CSV file have a mix of quoted and unquoted fields?  I.e., like 25,"This is text",abdd,"more quoted text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're dealing with a CSV that has some (or all) of its fields quoted.  If that's the case, I'd recommend using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` (which a lot of people don't seem to know about, and yes despite the namespace it can be used with C#).

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser;

Dim csvString As String = "25,""This is text"",abdd,""more quoted text"""

Dim parser as TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser(New StringReader(csvString))

' You can also read from a file
' Dim parser As TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser("mycsvfile.csv")

parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
parser.SetDelimiters(",")

Dim fields As String()

While Not parser.EndOfData

    fields = parser.ReadFields()

    For Each (field As String in fields)
        Console.WriteLine(field)
    Next
End While

parser.Close()
```

The output should be:

```
25
This is text
abdd
more quoted text
```

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

To Import this, you'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to your project.